# Java sort any array of objects

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have defined an abstract class as follows:

```
public abstract class Move implements Comparable<Move> {
protected int cell;
protected int weight;       

public int getWeight()
{
    return this.weight;
}

public void setWeight(int value)
{
    this.weight = value;
}

protected Move(int cell)
{
    this.cell = cell;
    this.weight = 0;
}

protected Move(int cell, int weight)
{
    this.cell = cell;
    this.weight = weight;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Move m) 
{
    return this.weight - m.weight;
}
```

I have an additional 2 classes that extend this class (classed MoveLeft and MoveRight). I add both types of objects to a List of type Move and then sort using Collections.sort:

```
List<Move> moves = new ArrayList<Move>(someSize);
moves.add(new MoveLeft(cell1));
moves.add(new MoveRight(cell2));
moves.add(new MoveRight(cell3));
moves.add(new MoveLeft(cell4));
Collections.sort(moves);
```

However, the list is being sorted by cell instead of by weight.

Is it not possible to mix different subclassed instances in the same sort?

Note: I'm setting a unique value for weight in the subclassed constructors.

Comment: Do the subclasses override compareTo?

Comment: No they don't. should they?

Comment: No ... it would be one explanation for the behavior you've seen.

Comment: Can you post the code that adds to the array and calls `Collections.sort()`?

Comment: Isn't all weight-values 0 since you only use the constructor setting cell-value and don't use setWeight()?

Comment: It seems to me that all your weights are 0, so the sorted order is arbitrary... (Seems that @ghdalum noticed that too, 2 seconds earlier ;-) )

Comment: Can we see the subclass constructors where you set the weight?

Comment: @Heuster Second place is just the first loser :)

Comment: I think a lot more information is needed, preferably an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). I have posted a comment in the form of an answer that contains a complete program consistent with the data so far. It sorts correctly. Any explanation has to explain why that program works.

Comment: It looks as though you may be adding your test data to the list in ascending cell order. If so, I suggest changing the order of the adds, because that would not distinguish between sorting in cell order and preserving the original order. Note that `Collections.sort()` is stable, so if all the weights in the Move `compareTo()` are equal, the result will be in the original order.

Comment: @Heuster Collections.sort for references is stable, so the sort order is not arbitrary. If all compareTo calls return 0, the original order is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You must create array of Move populate it with mix of derived classes upcasting it to Move and sort it as usual, then you can check you actual class using isntanceOf and downcast.

Comment: No casting required: that is not needed by the Collections.sort() method. In this case it will see the objects implement Comparable and call the compareTo() method regardless of the array type or the reference types that hold the instances.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a very long comment, rather than an answer.

I wrote a simple test program, and it appears to sort correctly. The output is `[Move [cell=10, weight=1], Move [cell=1, weight=100]]`, which is neither the order in which I added the elements, nor ascending cell order, but is ascending weight order.

I note that you have two constructor parameters of the same type. I suggest very careful checking that they are not getting switched around. If that is not the problem, I suggest trying to modify my test program to make it more similar to the real code, until it reproduces the problem. Here is my test program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Move> list = new ArrayList<Move>();
    list.add(new MoveRight(1, 100));
    list.add(new MoveLeft(10, 1));
    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println(list);
  }
}

abstract class Move implements Comparable<Move> {
  protected int cell;
  protected int weight;

  public int getWeight()
  {
    return this.weight;
  }

  public void setWeight(int value)
  {
    this.weight = value;
  }

  protected Move(int cell)
  {
    this.cell = cell;
    this.weight = 0;
  }

  protected Move(int cell, int weight)
  {
    this.cell = cell;
    this.weight = weight;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Move m)
  {
    return this.weight - m.weight;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Move [cell=" + cell + ", weight=" + weight + "]";
  }
}

class MoveLeft extends Move {

  protected MoveLeft(int cell, int weight) {
    super(cell, weight);
  }

}

class MoveRight extends Move {

  protected MoveRight(int cell, int weight) {
    super(cell, weight);
  }

}
```

Comment: Did that and I also made sure that each weight value is unique. It still sorts the objects by cell

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono In that case, I think your best approach is to work on an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), either by adding to my test program or by stripping down your real code.